# How do I add version control to uploaded files / images using Plone 4.1?

Tags: plone

I want to activate version control facility for uploaded files using Plone 4.1. E.g.Whenever an image is edited using Products.ImageEditor in Plone, I want the entry to appear in the history for the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to activate version control for images is to:

1) go to site setup
2) click Types
3) Select Image from the drop down
4) select Automatic versioning

Even with that, I don't think versioning will not automatically be performed for ImageEditor changes. ImageEditor just sets the field value for the image and does not emit any object modified events which I assume is required for plone's versioning to kick in.

FWIW, I'm the author of Products.ImageEditor. You can submit a ticket for the issue if you'd like: https://github.com/collective/Products.ImageEditor/issues

Comment: Thanks Vangheem. Using the above steps, it does save the history for the saved image changes. Thats what I required.